# Java, Selenium TimeoutException

Tags: java, selenium, junit

**Having this error:**

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
>   waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:
>   //select[@id='register-dob-month']/option[text()='5'] (tried for 5
>   second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

**SignUpPage:**

```
public class SignUpPage {
private WebDriver driver;

public SignUpPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

private By monthDropDown = By.cssSelector("select#register-dob-month");
private String monthDropDownOption = "//select[@id='register-dob-month']/option[text()='%s']";
private By dayField = By.cssSelector("input#register-dob-day");
private By yearField = By.cssSelector("input#register-dob-year");
private String genderRadioButton = "//li[@id='li-gender']/label[normalize-space()='Male']/input";
private By shareCheckbox = By.cssSelector("input#register-thirdparty");

public SignUpPage setMonth(String month) {
    driver.findElement(monthDropDown).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(visibilityOfElementLocated(xpath(format(monthDropDownOption, month)))).click();
    return this;
}


public SignUpPage typeDay(String day) {
    driver.findElement(dayField).sendKeys(day);
    return this;
}

public SignUpPage typeYear(String year) {
    driver.findElement(yearField).sendKeys(year);
    return this;
}
```

**SignUpTest:**

```
public class SignUpTest {
WebDriver driver;
SignUpPage page;

@Before
public  void setUp(){
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.spotify.com/int/signup");
}

@Test
public void typeInvalidYear(){
    page = new SignUpPage(driver);
    page.setMonth("5")
            .typeDay("20")
            .typeYear("88");
    Assert.assertTrue(page.isErrorVisible("Please enter a valid year."));
    Assert.assertFalse(page.isErrorVisible("When were you born?"));
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: it means your website was not opened for 5 seconds. increase implicitlyWait to a 30.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor no use, tried before

Comment: Have you debugged your xpath manually on chrome console?

Comment: @Роман What are you exactly trying to do within `xpath(format(monthDropDownOption, month))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occur because you use in xpath "**text()**", but should use "**//select[@id='register-dob-month']/option[@value='05'**]" 
see your HTML (screenshot - http://prntscr.com/k539il)
or
use "**May**", "**April**" instead of number of month.
Besides you can try to use Selenium Select class to operate with this dropdown:

```
WebElement Dropdown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select#register-dob-month"));

Select select = new Select(Dropdown);

select.selectByIndex(4);
//or
select.deselectByVisibleText("May");
```